# Problems scraping web page . (PHP)

Tags: php, json, parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm Really new at PHP.

I gonna get some value for webpage , I got problems can't not scrape this page.

is this any special page?

I want get that value I checked for pic attached.

[image]

I tried Snoopy.class , simple_html_dom or curl.

```
   require('simple_html_dom.php');
   $html = file_get_html('http://stock.kakao.com/m/rankers/211484');
   print $html;
```

I got blank in the browser as results

There should be some images in the browser by html code..

where are they? why I get blank page in the web browser?

I need these values in pic. help me please.

Comment: Maybe your IP is black listed?

Comment: By "blank page" do you mean the infamous [white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772851/1941241)?

Answer (score 0):

The page content is dynamically loaded with JavaScript so you cannot scrape it with php. If you really want the values I would just request the json itself and take it from there.

http://stock.kakao.com/api/rankers/211484.json

in this case the red percentage (154.52%) seems to be:

```
rankerDetail.contests[0].contestEarning.rate
```